# How exactly does Python find `__new__` and choose its arguments?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

While trying to implement some deep magic that I'd rather not get into here (I should be able to figure it out if I get an answer for this), it occurred to me that `__new__` doesn't work the same way for classes that define it, as for classes that don't. Specifically: when you define `__new__` yourself, it will be passed arguments that mirror those of `__init__`, but the default implementation doesn't accept any. This makes some sense, in that `object` is a builtin type and doesn't need those arguments for itself.

However, it leads to the following behaviour, which I find quite vexatious:

```py
>>> class example:
...     def __init__(self, x): # a parameter other than `self` is necessary to reproduce
...         pass
>>> example(1) # no problem, we can create instances.
<__main__.example object at 0x...>
>>> example.__new__ # it does exist:
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x...>
>>> old_new = example.__new__ # let's store it for later, and try something evil:
>>> example.__new__ = 'broken'
>>> example(1) # Okay, of course that will break it...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> example.__new__ = old_new # but we CAN'T FIX IT AGAIN
>>> example(1) # the argument isn't accepted any more:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
>>> example() # But we can't omit it either due to __init__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Okay, but that's just because we still have something explicitly attached to `example`, so it's shadowing the default, which breaks some descriptor thingy... right? **Except not**:

```py
>>> del example.__new__ # if we get rid of it, the problem persists
>>> example(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
>>> assert example.__new__ is old_new # even though the lookup gives us the same object!
```

The same thing still happens if we directly add and remove the attribute, without replacing it in between. Simply assigning and removing an attribute breaks the class, apparently irrevocably, and makes it impossible to instantiate. It's as if the class had some hidden attribute that tells it how to call `__new__`, which has been silently corrupted.

---

When we instantiate `example` at the start, how actually does Python find the base `__new__` (it apparently finds `object.__new__`, but is it looking directly in `object`? Getting there indirectly via `type`? Something else?), and how does it decide that this `__new__` should be called without arguments, even though it would pass an argument if we wrote a `__new__` method inside the class? Why does that logic break if we temporarily mess with the class' `__new__`, even if we restore everything such that there is no observable net change?

Comment: I ended up deciding that I don't *have to* solve this problem for my actual project - I can just wrap `__init__` instead - but it does sometimes impose a sort of two-step construction on the client code. I'm still interested in the underlying question.

Comment: What Python version are you on? `__new__` has some weirdness to it, but that weirdness shouldn't have produced the results you saw.

Comment: I find that interesting as a "how does this work"-question. But Perhaps leave the "What is the workaround for this?" out for now and ask it in a separate question (now or later). Otherwise I'm afraid this question might be closed as too broad to have a clear answer

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica `Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`.

Comment: @lucidbrot possibly, but it also seems possible that a workaround might be obvious given the answer to the first part.

Comment: `del example.__new__` is *supposed* to fix this. I think there might be a bug. I'm trying to figure it out now.

Comment: It occurs to me that there probably isn't a proper way to patch the `__new__` of an arbitrary class anyway, because of the situation where it doesn't have a `__new__` written but its `super()` *does*. There isn't a way to know in general what arguments should be passed to `super().__new__`, because they should match the arguments that the new object will pass to `super().__init__` - from the instance `__init__`, determined at runtime, after `__new__` has completed. So I'm going to remove that part of the question after all.

Comment: It looks like there is a check whether ``object.__new__`` has been "removed" from the class *at any point in time* that you cannot take back. Starting with your ``class``, it is perfectly fine to do ``example.__new__ = example.__new__`` and nothing breaks; but if instead we use ``example.__new__, example.__new__ = "foo", example.__new__`` the class is tainted immediately, even though the broken ``__new__`` is never called or even looked up.

Comment: ...oh. I see the bug now. This is weird, though - they [*fixed*](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/9ad11544bfb80b7881e0d567e40ef2fa2da58f02) this bug a while ago, then [reverted the change](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/c352620c92d2efcdf4940909d6de81cf9c336e0b) for some reason, then made a [different change](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/49010ee323eca5d6f5264f046ec1954d818fd5a7), then [reverted that too](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/49010ee323eca5d6f5264f046ec1954d818fd5a7). The commit comments are unhelpful.

Comment: Looking closer, the changed versions were buggy too. This part of the code has just gone through buggy version after buggy version.

Comment: (Whoops, wrong link on "different change" - that should have linked to [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5adfac2c1b7fb4f0782d097e7e0e6c5614965634).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issues you're seeing aren't related to how Python finds `__new__` or chooses its arguments. `__new__` receives every argument you're passing. The effects you observed come from specific code in `object.__new__`, combined with a bug in the logic for updating the C-level `tp_new` slot.

---

There's nothing special about how Python passes arguments to `__new__`. What's special is what `object.__new__` does with those arguments.

`object.__new__` and `object.__init__` expect one argument, the class to instantiate for `__new__` and the object to initialize for `__init__`. If they receive any extra arguments, they will either ignore the extra arguments or throw an exception, depending on what methods have been overridden:

1. If a class overrides exactly one of `__new__` or `__init__`, the non-overridden `object` method should ignore extra arguments, so people aren't forced to override both.
2. If a subclass `__new__` or `__init__` explicitly passes extra arguments to `object.__new__` or `object.__init__`, the `object` method should raise an exception.
3. If neither `__new__` nor `__init__` are overridden, both `object` methods should throw an exception for extra arguments.

There's a [big comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Objects/typeobject.c#L3663) in the source code talking about this.

---

At C level, `__new__` and `__init__` correspond to `tp_new` and `tp_init` function pointer slots in a class's memory layout. Under normal circumstances, if one of these methods is implemented in C, the slot will point directly to the C-level implementation, and a Python method object will be generated wrapping the C function. If the method is implemented in Python, the slot will point to the [`slot_tp_new`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Objects/typeobject.c#L6806) function, which searches the MRO for a `__new__` method object and calls it. When instantiating an object, Python will invoke `__new__` and `__init__` by calling the `tp_new` and `tp_init` function pointers.

`object.__new__` is implemented by the `object_new` C-level function, and `object.__init__` is implemented by `object_init`. `object`'s `tp_new` and `tp_init` slots are set to point to these functions.

`object_new` and `object_init` [check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Objects/typeobject.c#L3734) whether they're overridden by checking a class's `tp_new` and `tp_init` slots. If `tp_new` points to something other than `object_new`, then `__new__` has been overridden, and similar for `tp_init` and `__init__`.

```c
static PyObject *
object_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    if (excess_args(args, kwds)) {
        if (type->tp_new != object_new) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                            "object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)");
            return NULL;
        }
        ...
```

Now, when you assign or delete `__new__`, Python has to update the `tp_new` slot to reflect this. When you assign `__new__` on a class, Python sets the class's `tp_new` slot to the generic [`slot_tp_new`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Objects/typeobject.c#L6806) function, which searches for a `__new__` method and calls it. When you *delete* `__new__`, the class is supposed to re-inherit `tp_new` from the superclass, but [the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Objects/typeobject.c#L7297) has a bug:

```c
else if (Py_TYPE(descr) == &PyCFunction_Type &&
         PyCFunction_GET_FUNCTION(descr) ==
         (PyCFunction)(void(*)(void))tp_new_wrapper &&
         ptr == (void**)&type->tp_new)
{
    /* The __new__ wrapper is not a wrapper descriptor,
       so must be special-cased differently.
       If we don't do this, creating an instance will
       always use slot_tp_new which will look up
       __new__ in the MRO which will call tp_new_wrapper
       which will look through the base classes looking
       for a static base and call its tp_new (usually
       PyType_GenericNew), after performing various
       sanity checks and constructing a new argument
       list.  Cut all that nonsense short -- this speeds
       up instance creation tremendously. */
    specific = (void *)type->tp_new;
    /* XXX I'm not 100% sure that there isn't a hole
       in this reasoning that requires additional
       sanity checks.  I'll buy the first person to
       point out a bug in this reasoning a beer. */
}
```

In the `specific = (void *)type->tp_new;` line, `type` is the wrong type - it's the class whose slot we're trying to update, not the class we're supposed to inherit `tp_new` from.

When this code finds a `__new__` method written in C, instead of updating `tp_new` to point to the corresponding C function, it sets `tp_new` to whatever value it already had! It doesn't change `tp_new` at all!

---

So initially, your `example` class has `tp_new` set to `object_new`, and `object_new` ignores extra arguments because it sees that `__init__` is overridden and `__new__` isn't.

When you set `example.__new__ = 'broken'`, Python sets `example`'s `tp_new` to `slot_tp_new`. Nothing you do after that point changes `tp_new` to anything else, even though `del example.__new__` really should have.

When `object_new` finds that `example`'s `tp_new` is `slot_tp_new` instead of `object_new`, it rejects extra arguments and throws an exception.

---

The bug manifests in some other ways too. For example,

```
>>> class Example: pass
... 
>>> Example.__new__ = tuple.__new__
>>> Example()
<__main__.Example object at 0x7f9d0a38f400>
```

Before the `__new__` assignment, `Example` has `tp_new` set to `object_new`. When the example does `Example.__new__ = tuple.__new__`, Python finds that `tuple.__new__` is implemented in C, so it fails to update `tp_new`, leaving it set to `object_new`. Then, in `Example(1, 2, 3)`, `tuple.__new__` *should* raise an exception, because `tuple.__new__` isn't applicable to `Example`:

```
>>> tuple.__new__(Example)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: tuple.__new__(Example): Example is not a subtype of tuple
```

but because `tp_new` is still set to `object_new`, `object_new` gets called instead of `tuple.__new__`.

---

The devs have tried to fix the buggy code [several](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/9ad11544bfb80b7881e0d567e40ef2fa2da58f02) [times](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5adfac2c1b7fb4f0782d097e7e0e6c5614965634), but each fix was itself buggy and got reverted. The second attempt got closer, but broke multiple inheritance - see the [conversation](https://bugs.python.org/issue5322) in the bug tracker.

Comment: That's far more detail than I hoped for on the specific situation, but I'm still interested in how Python finds __new__ and chooses its arguments. When I call `Example(1)` and Python creates the underlying object, and looks up `Example.__new__`, what path does it take to find the C-level `object_new`, and *why doesn't* the `1` end up in `PyObject *args` (where it would be rejected)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: It *does* end up in `args`. `object_new` just doesn't reject the argument if it thinks only `__init__` is overridden.

Comment: After reading the actual source comment a couple of times as well, I get it. `object.__init__` and `object.__new__` really do have a `(*args, **kwargs)` signature (as they pretty much have to, on the C side of the fence), and the `TypeError`s for e.g. `object(1)` are raised explicitly. The remaining question - "how do the arguments get to `object.__new__` and thus the C `object_new` implementation?" - isn't a real question, because it's the same as for `object.__init__` - so, presumably, the simple and perfectly adequate answer is "they're forwarded from `type.__call__`".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Pretty much.

Comment: I also figured out that I don't have to worry about `super().__new__` because if its signature didn't match the derived `__init__`, the derived class would already have to implement `__new__` *or it would already be broken* (since it would get the `derived.__init__` args, which `object` can just ignore, but the base needs translated). So I really only have to special-case for `example.__new__ is object.__new__`. I'll ask the follow-up question separately, and also answer it, once I've written a MRE and also integrated my solution into my actual project.