# How to properly overload the __new__ method with arguments

Tags: python, class, object, overriding, overloading

I am trying to overload the `__new__` method for a class that requires arguments in `__init__`.

The following code exemplifies the issue:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        return
    
original_new = A.__new__
A.__new__ = None
A.__new__ = original_new

print(A(1))
```

It fails with:

```
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

how to properly overload `__new__` in such cases?

Comment: maybe [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70799600/how-exactly-does-python-find-new-and-choose-its-arguments)

Comment: the same as with any method, just do `def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):` and then the rest of the stuff (in the class body obvs)

Comment: @Matiiss: thanks, though it won't help cs I am trying to dynamically overload an already existing class.